# Which one is correct: "..., respectively, ..." or "..., respectively; ..."

Tags: orthography, semicolons

I am trying to understand which one is correct:

> Calculation of A and B matrices requires solving an equation 1 and an inequality 2, respectively, which are known to be difficult in general.

OR

> Calculation of A and B matrices requires solving an equation 1 and an inequality 2, respectively; which are known to be difficult in general.

What I want to say, is that we need to solve an equation 1 to get A, and an inequality 2 to get B. And that both equation and inequality are difficult to solve in general. Also, I don't explicitly give the equation and inequality, I just give their general forms, thus I use article "an" before "equation/inequality".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two cases appear to be identical except for the semi-colon.

In describing items, three equations or ten lemons, one uses *respectively* to mean each one of the items in turn. In mathematical cases the items are usually the same, not different. Solving equations 1, 2, and 3 respectively. If you have equations and inequalities the use of respectively is less important.

In general English you may use *respectively* to refer to any manner of mixed items to be handled each in turn. "Take out the trash, the papers and yourself, respectively."

I think either form is fine for your usage.

Answer (score -1):

The choice between comma and semicolon is arbitrary and unimportant.

What makes the sentence read poorly is word order and use of articles. To clarify I would write:

> Calculation of *matrix A and matrix B* requires solving equation 1 and
> inequality 2, respectively, *both of which* are known to be difficult in
> general.

What I have done is

1. Written the two matrices in full so as to separate them clearly in
   the reader’s mind, using the more normal “matrix A” rather than “A
   matrix”.
2. Removed the indefinite article from before “equation 1” and
   “inequality 2”, on the assumption that this is how they are referred
   to elsewhere. (If not, drop the “1” and “2”.)
3. Clarified the fact that both the equation and inequality are difficult, by adding “both of which”.

The moral is that when you feel something is wrong with a sentence, it may require more than a change in punctuation.